# Are flash drives always bootable?

Tags: usb, boot, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

I have this 8 gb toshiba flash drive and my motherboard also allows booting from removable devices. But I don't know, I've already tried to make the flash drive bootable and set in the bios to boot from USB. But it doesn't work. Are flash drives always bootable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can't give you any technical explanation, but I do know that I have a couple of flash drives that are bootable and working, and others that don't (using the same techniques). So I guess the answer is:

**No, they aren't always bootable**.

Not sure if there is any way of knowing if a flash drive is bootable other than trying it though.

Comment: i'd guess that your issues probably stem from your BIOS (or your motherboard USB chipset) rather than the drives themselves, but it's possible the drives' chipset/firmware is missing a feature or two.  if a flash drive isn't boot-capable, those are the only areas to blame.